# Limit to $\infty$ of integral function

Tags: integration, limits

Given the function:
$$F(x)=\int_0^{2x-x^2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt$$
My calculus book simply concludes that:
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}F(x)=-\infty$$

But why is this conclusion valid? Am I missing something "obvious"?

Comment: The integrand tends to a constant

Comment: @thedude But why?

Comment: When $t$ becomes large, $(1+t^2)^{-1}$ becomes 0 and cos(0)=1. It is then just a matter of integrating a constant

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think you mean $\cos(0)$?

Comment: @Anon123: sure, sorry. If $t^2$ is large, $\cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)\approx \cos(0)=1$. For every $t$ we have that $\cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)$ is bounded between the positive values $\cos(1)$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are calculating

$$ \lim_{x\to \pm\infty} F(x) = \lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \int_{0}^{2x-x^2}cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt $$

You are doing the improper integral

$$ \int_0^{-\infty} cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt $$

Using $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\cos{x}$ are even functions

$$ \int_0^{-\infty} cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt = -\int^0_{-\infty} cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt=-\int_0^{+\infty} cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt $$

We know $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\to 0$ when $x\to +\infty$, so $cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)\to \cos(0)=1$. Moreover, $\cos{x}$ in $[0,1]$ is positive and strictly decreasing, so our function is positive and strictly increasing in $[0,+\infty)$. Finally:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}  cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt \leq \int_0^{+\infty} cos(1) dt = +\infty$$

$$ \lim_{x\to \pm\infty} F(x) = -\int_0^{+\infty} cos\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt =-\infty$$

Comment: It is $\int_0^{+\infty} cos(0) dt$ not $\int_0^{+\infty} cos(1) dt$